# Is $\mathrm{d}H = C_P \mathrm{d}T$ and $\mathrm{d}U = C_V \mathrm{d}T$ always true?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is $\mathrm{d}H = C_P \mathrm{d}T$ and $\mathrm{d}U = C_V \mathrm{d}T$ always true for ideal gases?

Comment: Although (quite) clear from the context, it is *always* nice to define what the variables you use stand for. In particular, what definition of $C_P$ and $C_V$ are you using?

Comment: $\mathrm{d} Q = C_P \mathrm{d}T$

So it isn't the specific heat, but I guess that doesn't really matter in this case.